# Modifying an array value not working

Tags: php, arrays, replace, temporal

I'm trying to change one piece of information in an array. Here is what I have: (set.php)

```
require_once('config.php');

$spotid = $_GET['id'];

$array = & $spotsopen;
//$opennot = $spotsopen[$spotid];

$spotsopen[$spotid] = false;
```

and the config.php has the spotsopen array:

```
    $spotsopen = array(
    '1' => true,
    '2' => true,
    '3' => true,
    '4' => false,
    '5' => false,
    '6' => true,
    '7' => true,
    '8' => true,
    '9' => true,
    '10' => true,
    '11' => true,
    '12' => true,
    '13' => true,
    '14' => true,
    '15' => true,
    '16' => true,
    '17' => true,
    '18' => true,
    '19' => true
);
```

So I have a page, that redirects to set.php. There is changes the value of the key that is defined in the GET (set.php?id=). The code above does work, but as soon as I refresh it, it changes the value back to the previous one. I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: Changing that array will not survive refreshing the page as the refreshed page will reload the `config.php` file which contains hard coded values

Comment: I'm not sure if there is more, but you don't seem to be storing the modified values in any way. All php variables are lost as soon as the script finishes and when you run it again, al values will be as defined in the code. You probably want a database or config file to store the values. Then you can read, use, modify and store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot persist data like that across multiple requests. At every request, PHP starts from scratch, again executing your *config.php* file, defining the variable.

So if you do this request:

```
set.php?id=13
```

PHP does the necessary change, sends the page to the browser, and forgets about all your variables.

So if you then call another page, or the same one with another id, then PHP will start with blank information, and will not know about the previous change for id 13.

If you need this data to be retained across requests, there are several possibilities:

If it only needs to be persisted per user, then use [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). If on the other hand, it must be a global setting, the same for every user, then you should look to [file storage](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php), or to a [database](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), like MySql.

Comment: I was trying to make that system fast and not use databases. I have never tried file storage things. Is is fast? Or should I go with database?

Comment: If you have the choice, better go with a database, it will be much easier to query for things like "how many submissions happened in the last hour", and will be easily extendible for any future storage requirements you might think of.  If your host supports MySql, go for that, and make sure to use the modern functions to work with it (i.e. not *mysql_*, but *PDO*).

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code for file set.php:

```
require_once('config.php');

$spotid = $_GET['id'];

$array = & $spotsopen;

$spotsopen[$spotid] = "false";

header("Refresh:0; url=check-updated-value.php/?uid=$spotid");
```

This will give you the updated value of array:
Code for check-updated-value.php

```
require_once('config.php');
$id=$_GET['uid'];
echo "Updated value for id".$id."is".$spotsopen[$id];
```

Check the updated value by opening the page "check-updated-value.php"

In config.php, don't define array directly as it will define and initialize all values to true every time you will execute the file. Instead, load the values into the database like mysql and then fetch array from it.